# Make defined words appear standalone in left margin

Tags: formatting, indexing

I've seen this in textbooks before, so I imagine it's possible. What I would like is for a defined word to show up in the left margin for easy identification when scrolling through a document.

For example, with the following sentence I would like the word "bijection" to appear in the left margin, bolded.

```
A function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is called a \textbf{bijection} or bijective function if
it is both surjective and injective.
```

I have just wrapped it in `\textbf` for now, but this is find-replaceable in my current document.

I imagine this could be done with an indexing package, but haven't found a solution yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something along the lines of `\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\marginpar{\textsf{#1}}\textbf{#1}}` and the `\keyword{bijection}` would print the word in the margin in a sans serif and in the text in bold (to be tweaked as you like).  See also the CTAN packages for adding [marginal notes](http://www.ctan.org/topic/marginal) (or use the `memoir` class).

Comment: This works well, using `\reversemarginpar` to get it on the left side. I used this approach since it allows stacking if there are multiple "keyword"s on the same line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `marginnote` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\magic}[1]{%
\textbf{#1}\marginnote{#1}
}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
  A function $f:A     → B$ is called a \magic{bijection} or bijective function if
  it is both surjective and injective.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works well but I went with the `\marginpar` approach since it stacked words if more than one appears on a line.